# How can I add a Microsoft Bot to an Office 365 Group?

Tags: office365, botframework

The only way I have figured out as of now is through email.  However, because the bot's email is outside of an organization's AD, it is restricted only to public Office 365 Groups, not private.  In private groups, users never see the bot's response in the conversation.  In public groups they do.

I wonder if there is another way to integrate bots into Office365 Groups, similar to how the Office365 connectors can.

Answer (score 3):

You could firstly [create a mail user](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996335(v=exchg.160).aspx) , mail users (also known as mail-enabled users) have email addresses and accounts in the Exchange organization, but they don't have Exchange mailboxes. Email messages sent to mail users are delivered to the specified external email address. Use the New-MailUser cmdlet to create mail users and specify an external email :

```
New-MailUser -Name "Ed Meadows" -ExternalEmailAddress ed@tailspintoys.com -MicrosoftOnlineServicesID ed@tailspintoys -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'P@ssw0rd1' -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Then you could add the mail user to your  group .